# Java caesars cipher brute forcing

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, brute-force

I am new in Java and I need to write an algorithm for cracking Caesar's cipher using brute force and then matching the words from the dictionary to find the correct shift. That's the code I have written so far. I would really appreciate if somebody helps me with the implementation of shifting the letters and matching them with the file dictionary.txt.

```
private char[] alphabet = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
private char[] decodedText;
private String plainText;

public String producePlaintext(String cipherText) {
    //put each letter of the ciphertext in an array of characters in the upper case format
    char[] message = cipherText.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    //loop through all the possible keys
    for (int key = 0; key < alphabet.length; key++) {
        //set the value of the decrypted array of characters to be the same as the length of the cipher text
        decodedText = new char[message.length];
        //loop through the characters of the ciphertext
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {

            //if character is not space
            if (message[i] != ' ') {
                //shift the letters

            }else{
                decodedText[i] = ' ';
            }
        }
        plainText = String.valueOf(decodedText);
    }
    return plainText;
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have specifically? You probably need a validation function that a produced plaintext is the real plaintext. Otherwise you cannot decrypt it. You could however print all possible 26 plaintexts and try to select the one that is the real plaintext by looking for known words. This could also be done programmatically, but then you need a word list.

Comment: My problem is printing all the possible plaintexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the alphabet array to `List` to use the `indexOf` method:

```
private List<Character> alphabetList = java.util.Arrays.asList(alphabet);
```

Inside you can then do the following:

```
decodedText[i] = alphabet[(alphabetList.indexOf(message[i])+key) % alphabet.length];
```

You should probably begin the iteration of `key` with `1` and not with `0`, because you will then just get the ciphertext back.

Complete solution:

```
public class Test01 {

    private Character[] alphabet = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    private char[] decodedText;
    private String[] plainText;
    private java.util.List<Character> alphabetList;

    public Test01(){
        alphabetList = java.util.Arrays.asList(alphabet);
        plainText = new String[alphabet.length];
    }

    public String[] producePlaintext(String cipherText) {
        //put each letter of the ciphertext in an array of characters in the upper case format
        char[] message = cipherText.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        //loop through all the possible keys
        for (int key = 0; key < alphabet.length; key++) {
            //set the value of the decrypted array of characters to be the same as the length of the cipher text
            decodedText = new char[message.length];
            //loop through the characters of the ciphertext
            for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {

                //if character is not space
                if (message[i] != ' ') {
                    //shift the letters
                    decodedText[i] = alphabet[(alphabetList.indexOf(message[i])+key) % alphabet.length];
                }else{
                    decodedText[i] = ' ';
                }
            }
            plainText[key] = String.valueOf(decodedText);
        }
        return plainText;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test01 t = new Test01();
        for(String pt : t.producePlaintext("abc")) {
            System.out.println(pt);
        }
    }

}
```

Note the differences of the char types.

Comment: What it variable `j`? If I use `i` instead of it, I keep getting ZZZ as plain text.

Comment: Final solution is there. You needed to return all plaintexts and not only the last one.